# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Not yet implemented

Tags: android, selenium, xpath, appium

```
 dr.switchTo().frame(dr.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Baby Corn Pepper Fry']")));
 dr.findElement(By.id("com.msf.smartd.merchant:id/menu_item_switch")).click();
```

I tried to switch the focus to the menu item "Baby Corn Pepper Fry". and used the above code. Getting error as WebDriverException.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due appium version, need to upgrade appium.